# Call function by a string from imported module

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I call a function from imported module?

Usually I would do something like `global[method](args)` but imported modules are wrapped in an anonymous scope and they are not accessible through `global`.

I'm using ES6 with Node.js (v10.16.0), Nodemon (v2.0.1) and Babel.

```js
import myFunction from './methods/myFunction';
const method = 'myFunction';
console.log(method in global); //false
console.log(global[method]); //undefined
```

myFunction.js:

```js
const myFunction=()=> { console.log('x') };
export default myFunction;
```

Comment: What is in your `./methods/myFunction`?

Comment: @Dijkstra Edit: myFunction.js  in question.

Comment: I believe you should just call `myFunction()`.

Comment: @Dijkstra This is just example. String will be set from console by a user.

Answer (score 2):

would it work to have a mapping object you define yourself and use it like you're trying to use 'global'?

ex.

```
const functionMapper = {
  myFunction: myFunction,
  someOtherFunction: someOtherFunction,
};

functionMapper['myFunction'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs is not browser when meaning, if you define function it be added to window/global. To define in global u need to add in global.

If you realy want to add in global. try this.

```
//myFunction.js:
let global = global || window
global["myFunction"] = ()=> { console.log('x') };

// Now access:
import './methods/myFunction';
const method = 'myFunction';
console.log(method in global); //false
console.log(global[method]); //undefined
```